# Confused about 'puts'

Tags: word-usage

I am confused about using the future tense of the word 'put' in a plural sentence.

Which is correct:

> **A:** Value the ones who **puts** it back.

or:

> **B:** Value the ones who put it back.

Comment: what future tense?

Answer (score 1):

Version B is the correct one:

> Value the ones who put it back.

If the subject was singular, though, we could use *puts* instead:

> **C:** Value the one who puts it back.
>   **D:** Value the one who put it back.

Version D is in the past tense: the act of putting it back has already happened.

Version C is talking about habitual action, as in: *Value the one who [always] puts it back.*

For future tense, I would say that should be:

> **E:** Value the one(s) who will put it back.

(The subject can be singular or plural in that sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

"Who" may be singular or plural. Here, it refers to "ones", which is plural, and so takes a plural verb, so "put".